# Generating variable Leaflet marker colors bases on arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

I'm trying to give the points on my map a dynamic color, based on an array filled with colors.

Currently, the colors in my code are defined in a function:

```
function getColor(keten) {
    return  keten == "MacDonalds"   ? '#800888' :
            keten == "Subway"       ? '#969696' :
            keten == "KFC"          ? '#081d58' :
                                      '#252525' ;
    }
```

Which is called in Leaflet:

```
    window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var markerStyle = { 
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Fastfoodketen),
........
```

Because of reasons, I now have dynamic data, and need to change my code a bit.

I've created two arrays, one filled with colors and one (dynamically) filled with restaurant chain names. Then I loop through both arrays and try to generate a variable that looks like the data in my `getColor()` function. That variable could then be returned in the same way.

```
arrayKleur =  ["#a6cee3", "#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#33a02c", "#fb9a99", "#e31a1c", "#fdbf6f", "#ff7f00", "#6a3d9a", "#b15928"];
// filled for testing purposes, normally it's filled somewhere else
arrayKeten =  ["Kwalitaria", "NYPizza", "Dominos", "BurgerKing", "KFC", "Subway", "MacDonalds"];

var leafletData = [];

for (i= 0; i < arrayKeten.length; i++){
    leafletData += 'keten == '+arrayKeten[i]+'   ? '+arrayKleur[i]+' :</br>';
    }
leafletData += 'red;' ;

function getColor(keten) {
    return  leafletData;
    }
```

With this new code I get a `string` which look just like the content of `getColor()`, but I think Leaflet can't work with a `string`, because all the markers on my map are black now.

I tried changing my original `getColor()` function to incorporate my arrays, just to see if it works.

```
function getColor(keten) {
    return  keten == arrayKeten[0]   ? arrayKleur[0]:
            keten == arrayKeten[1]   ? arrayKleur[1]:
            keten == arrayKeten[2]   ? arrayKleur[2]:
                                      '#999999' ;
    }
```

This works flawlessly, so I think I'm pretty close to the solution with my `string`.

**What do I need to change to get my code to work properly? Or am I maybe overcomplicating things?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Your string is not a color, is a string of text that looks like javascript but is not evaluated. And using `eval()` is wrong 99.9999% of the time.

Instead, use good ol' [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
function getColor(keten) {
    var i = arrayKeten.indexOf(keten);
    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
    } else {
        return '#999999';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an object for the colors with a default value?

```
function getColor(keten) {
    var colors = { Kwalitaria: "#a6cee3", NYPizza: "#1f78b4", Dominos: "#b2df8a", BurgerKing: "#33a02c", KFC: "#fb9a99", Subway: "#e31a1c", MacDonalds: "#fdbf6f" };
    return colors[keten] || '#999999';
}
```

Comment: The chain data is variable and could well be something completely different from MacDonalds, KFC etc. In this solution the chain data is still static, just like it is in my original code.

Comment: you could build the object upon the dynamic arrays you have.